# How to store string from user input using a widget in emacs?

Tags: emacs, widget, user-input, store

I have created a widget with an editable-field.

```
 (widget-create 'editable-field
                 :size 13
                 :format  "name: %v \n"
                 "Type in your name")
```

How can I now store only the user input?
I tried **setq** before **widget-create**
but it stores the entire widget definition.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to store the user input using the notify field in the widget creation.

```
 (widget-create 'editable-field
                 :size 13
                 :format  "name: %v \n"
                 ;;"Type in your name"
                 :notify (lambda (widget &rest ignore)
                                  (setq *name*  (widget-value widget)))
    )
```